# Change bootstrap entry in @NgModule on the fly

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a web application that can only be called with example.com/index.html. Unfortunately no parameters can be passed. Don't ask why. It is a long story.
index.html contains the code for an Angular frontend with two components(FirstComponent and SecondComponent). In the index.html before it is executed I can write in two strings via tags, which are stored in the LocalStorage. They will be read when the index.html is executed with Javascript. I want the component to be started to be read from the LocalStorage and then called.
Routing is no option because the application accepts only example.com/index.html.

The code below doesn't work.

```
app.module.ts

const m = new Map();
map1.set("first",AppComponent);
map1.set("second",SecondComponent);

@NgModule({
...
 bootstrap: [m.get(String that I got from locat storage("first" or "second"))]
...
```

Comment: Why you can't create a new root component which will decide which component show, which hide?

Answer (score 0):

You could choose bootstrap component during bootstrapping process like this:

```js
import { ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, NgModule, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent1 } from './app.component1';
import { AppComponent2 } from './app.component2';
import { NxWelcomeComponent } from './nx-welcome.component';

const components = [AppComponent1,AppComponent2];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent1, AppComponent2, NxWelcomeComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: components,
})
export class AppModule {

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
     const componentName = localStorage.getItem('componentName');

    const filteredComponent = components.find(
      (component: Type<{}>) => component.name === componentName
    );

    if (filteredComponent) {
      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(filteredComponent);
      this.appRef.bootstrap(factory);
    }
}
```